# Test NG Cucumber Parallel Automation with Dynamic test tags and param

Tags: cucumber, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am currently looking to run multiple test in cucumber in parallel using testng and I successfully managed to do that.
Now my requirement is rather than having multiple Test TAGS in the testNG file with different parameters take it from the maven command line. So I can do automation without editing the testNg.xml file. Is there a way to achieve it? Please find my current testng.xml configuration.

testng.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Testng Cucumber Suite" thread-count="2"   parallel="tests">

<!--  In order to run test cases please copy and one test and add make sure you add relevant parameters -->
  <test name="Run_Nexus_06">
       <parameter name="deviceName" value="Google Nexus 6" />
            <parameter name="platformVersion" value="6.0" />
        <classes>
            <class name="cucumber.mobile.ParallelRunner">
            </class>
        </classes>

  </test>

    <test name="Run_Google_Pixel">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="Google Pixel" />
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="7.1" />
        <classes>
            <class name="cucumber.mobile.ParallelRunner">
            </class>
        </classes> 
    </test> 

</suite>
```

Runner Class :

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/html/", "json:target/cucumber.json", "junit:TEST-all.xml"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features/SignUp.feature", glue = {"steps"}, tags = {"@Mobile"})
public class ParallelRunner  extends Hook{

       List<Object[]> data;
    //<parameter name="deviceName" value="Google Pixel" />
   // <parameter name="platformVersion" value="7.1" />
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({"deviceName","platformVersion"})
    public void bb(String deviceName, String platformVersion){
        Device device = new Device();
        device.setDeviceName(deviceName);
        device.setOsVersion(platformVersion);
        DeviceFactory.setDevice(device);
        System.out.println("Device" + deviceName + "Os Version" + platformVersion + "   " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }


}
```

Comment: you want to read out test parameter from cmd ? like deviceName. Is this your requirement or u want to pass @CucumberOptions tags from cmd.

Comment: @ThrSociety yup exactly. (like deviceName )So every time I do not need to update my testNg.xml file manually. Also, I want to bring this to Jenkins job where user can select params and dynamically pass to TestNg file and execute

Comment: Thanks, @TheSociety I have found a solution from a different article :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was glad that I found this post. Very useful if anyone trying to achieve the same thing. [Dynamic Test ng IAlterSuiteListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737333/testng-parallel-execution-with-selenium)

Maven command  :> mvn compile test  -DdeviceFlavors="Google Nexus 6","Google Pixel" -DdeviceOsFlavors="6.0","7.1" -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml