# How to duplicate XML Test Tags programmatically in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

My project is a Test Automation project comprising Selenium Java with TestNG. I have a testng XML. I am triggering the test cases from Jenkins. I send the browser information from Jenkins. If I have multiple browsers mentioned in Jenkins, I want the test tag to duplicate accordingly.

```
 <test name="VSR" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="CHROME"/>
    <parameter name="Headless" value="false"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycomp.HomePageTestcases" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

So, when I pass `CHROME,FIREFOX` from Jenkins, I want it to get duplicated "programmatically". Something like this:

```
 <test name="VSR" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="CHROME"/>
    <parameter name="Headless" value="false"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycomp.HomePageTestcases" />
    </classes>
</test>

 <test name="VSR" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
    <parameter name="Browser" value="FIREFOX"/>
    <parameter name="Headless" value="false"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycomp.HomePageTestcases" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

In order to duplicate test tag, I made this method. I am calling this method in @BeforeSuite:

```
public void duplicateTestTagForEachBrowser(ITestContext context) {
    try {
        List<XmlTest> tests = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getTests();
        int testSize = tests.size();
        List<String> browsers = Arrays.asList(System.getenv("Browser")).split(","));
        for (int j = 0; j < testSize; j++) {
            tests.get(j).clone();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
            tests.get(i).setName(tests.get(i).getName() + "_" + browsers.get(i % browsers.size()));
        }
        context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().setTests(tests);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Its duplicating test tags in ITestContext. But when I check `intercept` method of `MethodInterceptorListener`, I couldn't find the test methods getting duplicated.


Could some one help me understand what I was doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution via IAlterSuiteListener.

Took the solution from : [TestNG Parallel execution with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737333/testng-parallel-execution-with-selenium)

```
public class AlterSuiteListener implements IAlterSuiteListener {

@Override
public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
    for (int i = 0; i < suites.size(); i++) {
        XmlSuite xmlSuite = suites.get(0);
        List<XmlTest> tests = suites.get(i).getTests();
        int xmlTestSize = tests.size();
        List<String> browsers = Arrays.asList(System.getenv("Browser").split(","));
        List<XmlTest> expectedXmlTests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int xmlTestIndex = 0; xmlTestIndex < xmlTestSize; xmlTestIndex++) {
            XmlTest defaultXmlTest = tests.get(xmlTestIndex);
            for (String browser : browsers) {
                XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
                xmlTest.setName(defaultXmlTest.getName() + "_" + browser);
                xmlTest.setClasses(defaultXmlTest.getClasses());
                xmlTest.setThreadCount(defaultXmlTest.getThreadCount());
                xmlTest.setParallel(defaultXmlTest.getParallel());
                Map<String, String> allParameters = defaultXmlTest.getAllParameters();
                allParameters.put("Browser",browser);
                xmlTest.setParameters(allParameters);
                expectedXmlTests.add(xmlTest);
            }
        }
        xmlSuite.setTests(expectedXmlTests);
    }
}
}
```

That duplicateTestTagForEachBrowser is not required. I had to add this listener in XML file, that's it. It worked like charm.